# How can I dynamically switch react components using a string or state?

Tags: string, reactjs, dynamic, components

Hopefully the script bellow will show roughly what I am trying to achieve.

But essentially, using a string stored in a state, be able to have a component holder dynamically load different components on change.

So you will see 2 component imported at the top (but ideally these could be a 100 different ones.

A `currentSlide` state that holds the string name of the component.

And a SlideLoader component that would ideally load imported components based on a string name.

Then the button's switch the component through resetting the state name.

Thank you!

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  View,
  Text,
  StyleSheet,
} from 'react-native';

import SlideA from './slideA';
import SlideB from './slideB';

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  dummyContainer: {
    flex: 0,
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    position: 'absolute',
    top: 0,
    bottom: 0,
    left: 0,
    right: 0,
    backgroundColor: '#999999',
  },
  buttonHolder: {
    position: 'absolute',
    top: 4,
    left: 0,
  },
  button: {
    height: 50,
    width: 300,
    backgroundColor: 'red',
    marginBottom: 4,
    textAlignVertical: 'center',
    textAlign: 'center',
    fontWeight: 'bold',
  },
});

export default class Switcher extends Component {
  constructor(props, context) {
    super(props, context);
    let state = {
      currentSlide: 'SlideA',
    }
  }

  render() {
    // obvisously wrong part...
    let SlideLoader = this.state.currentSlide;
    // end of obvisously wrong part...

    return (
      <View
        style={[
          styles.dummyContainer,
        ]}
      >

        <SlideLoader />

        <View
          style={styles.buttonHolder}
        >
          <Text
            onPress={() => {
              console.log('SLID A');
              setState({ currentSlide: 'SlideA' });
            }}
            style={[styles.button]}
          >
            Slide A
          </Text>
          <Text
            onPress={() => {
              console.log('SLID B');
              setState({ currentSlide: 'SlideB' });
            }}
            style={[styles.button]}
          >
            Slide B
          </Text>
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok here we go :

```
 render() {
    let SlideLoader;
  if(this.state.currentSlide == 'SlideA')
  SlideLoader=<SlideA />
  else
  SlideLoader=<SlideB />

    return (
      <View
        style={[
          styles.dummyContainer,
        ]}
      >

        {SlideLoader}

        <View
          style={styles.buttonHolder}
        >
          <Text
            onPress={() => {
              console.log('SLID A');
              setState({ currentSlide: 'SlideA' });
            }}
            style={[styles.button]}
          >
            Slide A
          </Text>
          <Text
            onPress={() => {
              console.log('SLID B');
              setState({ currentSlide: 'SlideB' });
            }}
            style={[styles.button]}
          >
            Slide B
          </Text>
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
```

Cheers:)

Comment: Thank you that is what I was looking for!

Comment: Welcome brother :)